# Why are Cordova StatusBar methods missing execution?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on a Cordova Ionic application, and I'm trying to make the Status Bar color match the background color used in the header of my application (as most apps do these days).

Thus, I am using [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar) plugin. However, whenever I call any of the methods associated with this Apache Cordova plugin, "missing exec:StatusBar.*methodName*" is printed to the browser console and the function is not executed.

Here is an example:
(Note that I am using the AngularJS .run method)

```
.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        console.log(StatusBar);
        StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#387EF5");
    });
```

While debugging the application, if I check the browser logs, "missing exec:StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString" was printed to the console. An image showing an example of this can be seen by clicking on the link below:

[screenshot of browser logs due to the code shown above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUT6R.png)

Because the StatusBar object correctly prints to the browser logs, I know the StatusBar object is available to the .run function. However, I cannot explain why the methods are not executing. Please let me know how I can fix this issue.

Also, please note that this is my first time asking a question on stack overflow, so please let me know what I can do to improve how I ask questions in the future. Thanks!

Edit:

Here is the config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.ionicblankapp" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>ionic-blankapp</name>
  <description>
        An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
    </description>
  <author email="you@example.com" href="http://example.com.com/">
      Your Name Here
    </author>
  <content src="index.html" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
  </feature>
  <preference name="KeepRunning" value="True" />
  <preference name="ShowTitle" value="True" />
  <preference name="InAppBrowserStorageEnabled" value="True" />
  <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="True" />
  <preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.0.2" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.2.1" />
  <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~1.0.8" />
  <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
  <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#387EF5" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" version="2.1.3" />
</widget>
```

I used the Visual Studio config.xml package manager (Designer view) to add the plugin cordova-plugin-statusbar (version 2.1.3)

I am using cordova android platform version 5.2.2 and ios 4.2.1 (the most recent versions of both).

Comment: can i see your config.xml and command you used for adding status-bar plugin ?

Comment: plugin supports Android 5+ only